# How to covert List to Tree without stack overflow

Tags: scala

I have a problem with **List[(nodeID, parentID)] -> Tree structure**

```
val tree: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,1),(5,4),(6,2),(7,6))
```

my tree case class

```
case class Tree(value: Int, subTree: List[Tree])
```

my code

```
def DFS(tree: List[(Int, Int)], id: Int): List[Tree] = {
     if(tree.isEmpty) Nil
     else List(Tree(id, tree.filter(x => x._2 == id).flatMap(x => DFS(tree, x._1))))}
```

result

```
List(Tree(0,List(Tree(1,List(Tree(4,List(Tree(5,List()))))), Tree(2,List(Tree(6,List(Tree(7,List()))))), Tree(3,List()))))
```

and I found stack overflow for large data in list

so I want to change it to **tail-recursive, map or fold**

Comment: make sure that your recursive code is tail-recursive or it will cause stack-overflow on large inputs

Comment: change it to tail-recursive call pls, I don't know how to do that

Comment: The `value` attribute of `Tree` is the `ID`, right?

Comment: yes, a value is ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot to improve from performance point of view, but it seems to work:

```
val tree: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,1),(5,4),(6,2),(7,6))
case class Tree(value: Int, subTree: List[Tree])

// Sort in reverse BFS order
@annotation.tailrec
def BFS(tree: List[(Int, Int)], ids: List[(Int, Int)], acc: List[(Int, Int)]): List[(Int, Int)] = {
  ids match {
    case Nil => acc
    case head::tail =>
      BFS(tree, tail ++ tree.filter(_._2 == head._1), head::acc) 
  }
}

// acc: List of (parent, Tree)
@annotation.tailrec
def fold(bfs: List[(Int, Int)], acc: List[(Int, Tree)]): List[(Int, Tree)] = {
  bfs match {
    case Nil => acc
    case head::tail =>
      val (l, r) = acc.partition(_._1 == head._1)
      fold(tail, (head._2, Tree(head._1, l.map(_._2))) :: r)
  }
}

fold(BFS(tree, List((0, 0)), Nil), Nil).map(_._2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `tree` parameter to `DFS` is never getting smaller. You will therefore never hit the base case.

Should the call be this instead: `DFS(tree.tail, x._1)`?

Comment: DFS(tree.tail, x._1) as same as  DFS(tree, x._1)

Answer (score 0):

Though making it tail recursive may take some time, you can get it working as following.

```
val tree: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,1),(5,4),(6,2),(7,6))

def DFS(tree: List[(Int, Int)], id: Int): List[Tree] = tree match {
  case Nil => List[Tree]()
  case list =>
    val (children, others) => list.partition(x => x._2 == id)
    List(Tree(id, children.flatMap(x => DFS(others, x._1))))
}
```